# RadioButtons within a RadioGroup check/uncheck randomly in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I cannot crack this problem: I have a listview with 10 questions. For each question there are three answers (RadioButtons) that are organized within a RadioGroup. The problem is that everytime I scroll the list the RadioButtons randomly check/uncheck. I know that I have to somehow save the answers and "reload" them everytime the list is scrolled but I just can`t get it working. I have already looked on the Internet and studied these topics:

[On scrolling List View radio button gets unchecked by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273391/on-scrolling-list-view-radio-button-gets-unchecked-by-itself) 
[If I check a radio button in listview then other radio buttons of listview get checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120932/if-i-check-a-radio-button-in-listview-then-other-radio-buttons-of-listview-get-c) 
[Radio Button gets uncked and automatically checked in listview scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205437/radio-button-gets-uncked-and-automatically-checked-in-listview-scrolling) 
[Checking RadioButton of RadioGroup in ListView checks other item button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018245/checking-radiobutton-of-radiogroup-in-listview-checks-other-item-button) 
[Checkbox unchecked when I scroll listview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895763/checkbox-unchecked-when-i-scroll-listview-on-android) 
Here is my adapter code:

```
public class adapterEdit extends ArrayAdapter<AnswerModel> {

private final ArrayList<AnswerModel> mQuestions;
private final Activity mContext;




public adapterEdit(Activity context, ArrayList<AnswerModel> questions){
    super(context,0,questions);
    this.mQuestions = questions;
    this.mContext = context;



}
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected RadioButton one;
    protected RadioButton two;
    protected RadioButton three;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if( convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textOfQuestion);

        holder.one = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerOne);
        holder.one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                mQuestions.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });

        holder.two = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerTwo);
        holder.two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                mQuestions.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });

        holder.three = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerThree);
        holder.three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                mQuestions.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
            }
        });



        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.answerOne, holder.one);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.answerTwo, holder.two);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.answerThree, holder.three);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.one.setTag(position);
    holder.two.setTag(position);
    holder.three.setTag(position);


    holder.text.setText(mQuestions.get(position).getQuestion());

    holder.one.setText(mQuestions.get(position).getAnswerOne());
    holder.one.setChecked(mQuestions.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.two.setText(mQuestions.get(position).getAnswerTwo());
    holder.two.setChecked(mQuestions.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.three.setText(mQuestions.get(position).getAnswerThree());
    holder.three.setChecked(mQuestions.get(position).isSelected());




    return convertView;}}
```

Here is the class of the object that I'm using in the listview:

```
public class AnswerModel {

private String mQuestion;
private String mAnswerOne;
private String mAnswerTwo;
private String mAnswerThree;
private boolean selected = false;


public AnswerModel (String question, String answerOne, String answerTwo, String answerThree) {
    this.mQuestion = question;
    this.mAnswerOne = answerOne;
    this.mAnswerTwo = answerTwo;
    this.mAnswerThree = answerThree;
}

public String getQuestion(){return mQuestion;}
public String getAnswerOne(){return mAnswerOne;}
public String getAnswerTwo(){return mAnswerTwo;}
public String getAnswerThree(){return mAnswerThree;}
public boolean isSelected() {return selected;}
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}}
```

And the XML of the list item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.harrypotterfanquiz.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOfQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/questionColor"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/questionOne"
        android:textAppearance="@style/appearanceBody" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/questionOneA" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/questionOneB" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answerThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/questionOneC" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that the problem is somwhere in adapter. I've been trying to solve this for over a week. If you have any advice or solution I will be very grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my app. I solved with saving unique model field inside ViewHolder. Then I have check every time before setting Checkbox if the model has the same unique field as ViewHolder. Only then was Checkbox set to correct condition like this:

```
if(holder.uniqueField == mQuestions.get(position).uniqueField) {
    holder.one.setChecked(mQuestions.get(position).isSelected());
}
```

Is not cleanest, but it is work.